WorkManager stops working after some time
I'm trying to develop a simple android app (jetpack compose + kotlin) for daily therapy monitoring. User set some things to do at some hour in the day (take a pill, blood pressure measuring...), which are saved in a Room database. I would like that app check every 30 minutes if there is an incoming therapy to do in next 30 minutes, showing a notification in that case. I thought that WorkManager was the best way to do this, since I want that app could send notification even if not active. Here is my code about workmanager:
//MainActivity
private lateinit var workManager: WorkManager
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<IncomingTherapyWorker>(30,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(IncomingTherapyWorker.WORKER_TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE, workRequest)

        //Notifictaion channel creation
        val therapyNotificationService = TherapyNotificationService(this)
        therapyNotificationService.createNotificationChannel()
        //
        setContent {...

@HiltWorker
class IncomingTherapyWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted parameters: WorkerParameters,
    private val repository: TherapyRepository
) : CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {

    val terapyNotificationService = TherapyNotificationService(context = context)

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {

            //let's log on a file
            val dataNow = LocalDateTime.now()
            val folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
            val file = File(folder,"RegistroWorker.txt")
            val outputStream = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                FileOutputStream(file, true)
            }

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                outputStream.write(
                    String.format(
                        "%4d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d \n",
                        dataNow.year,
                        dataNow.monthValue,
                        dataNow.dayOfMonth,
                        dataNow.hour,
                        dataNow.minute,
                        dataNow.second
                    ).toByteArray()
                )
                outputStream.close()
            }
            //

            var messaggio: String = ""
            val listaTerapie = repository.getTherapylist()
            val iterator = listaTerapie.listIterator()
            iterator.forEach { terapia ->
                val incomingOutput = isTherapyIncoming(terapia)
                if(incomingOutput.esito) {
                    messaggio = messaggio + terapia.etichetta + " " + incomingOutput.messaggio + "\r\n"
                }
            }

            if(!messaggio.isEmpty())
                terapyNotificationService.sendTherapyNotification(messaggio)

            return Result.success()
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            throwable.message?.let { Log.d(WORKER_TAG, it) }
            throwable.cause?.let { Log.d(WORKER_TAG, it.cause.toString()) }
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val WORKER_TAG = "TherapySeeker"
    }
}

This work, but only for a while. Expecially when device is turned off or app is minimized, Worker stops working.
I understand, or I think I understood, that doze mode and battery saving is involved in this.
Is there anything wrong in my code?
Is it possible to have persistent worker in all conditions?

WorkManager stopped working... The title of this question just put a smile on my face, thank you! :)

You're welcome...but it is "stops", not "stopped" (just one time). This happen always, everytime I open the app, workmanger do what it should until something blocks it, without throwing any exception. I just would like to understand if there is a way to have a thread which works even if app is closed and phone is in doze mode. For example: an app driving an insulin pump surely should work continuously in all conditions, since it should continuously read CGM values and drive pump: how could it be done?

I am not proficient with WorkManager, but apps like you mentioned would probably ask the user at the first startup to whitelist their app from doze mode:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases There is a certain intent for that: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

I tried a different approach: a repeating Alarm (setInexactRepeating) triggering every 30 min, which launch a OneTimeWorkmamager. The alarm triggerd just 2 times, then disappeared. I did not reboot the system, and in that case, I added functionality to restart alarm at reboot...should I use an exact Alarm?

Inexact alarms might be delayed by around one hour. If it is a health-critical app, you could argue that it is necessary to set exact alarms. However, you can't repeat exact alarms, so you would have to schedule them one by one. See also this question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78764012/delay-in-notification-android-kotlin

The goal should be monitoring personal therapies giving alerts before I should do one of them. Imagine that I need to:

take a pill 4 times a day (9:00, 15:00, 17:00, 20:00) from today to 12th of Oct
have a drip once every three days until 5th Oct at 17:00
measure glucose 4 times a day (7:30, 12:30, 16:30, 22:00) forever
...
How many alarms should I schedule? That's why i thought that PeriodicWork could be the best solution, considering that the doWork() should read Room database to check for incoming therapy. But from log file I see that it stops working. Same happen with Alarms


Maybe an exact alarm relaunching itself is the solution?

How are the therapies added to the Room database? Do you add them only inside the App? Or is the App fetching data from the cloud?

They are added only inside App

Please have a look at the documentation of PeriodicWorkRequest:

Periodic work is intended for use cases where you want a fairly consistent delay between consecutive runs, and you are willing to accept inexactness due to battery optimizations and doze mode.


If you need to schedule work that happens exactly at a certain time or only during a certain time window, you should consider using OneTimeWorkRequests.

I am not very proficient with this topic, but it seems to me that the general roadmap for your use case could be:

Create some OneTimeWorkRequests, as these are not restricted by doze mode or battery optimization.
Within a OneTimeWorkRequest,

you check the Room database for incoming therapies
you schedule an Alarm using setExact to ensure that the alarm is delivered exactly at the specified time, independent of doze mode or battery optimization.
you schedule the next OneTimeWorkRequest.



If the therapies are only added individually to the Room database through the App, then it actually would be enough to just call AlarmManager.setExact() whenever a new entry was added to the database.

Thank you for your suggestion, I'll immediately try to follow it
